# Traveling from Dubai to Saudi Arabia for Umrah

Tags: visas, driving, road-trips, uae, saudi-arabia

As per new Visa rules in Saudi Arabia, Visa-holding expats can perform Umrah. My question is, can we travel there via personal vehicle now, or is travel by road in private vehicles still not allowed for expats?

Comment: Expats? Are you a Saudi citizen?

Comment: What do you mean "can we travel via personal vehicle"? do you mean if you can enter Saudi by your car, or enter Mecca by your car?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Expat in UAE, I presume, and looking to drive to Mecca from there.